# MVC 4 Installation Failure- Error Code 0x80070643

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to install MVC 4 in my visual studio 2010 but once I try to install, it's showing me error which can see my given attached file.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WreXm.png)

[Check my error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Aa9O.png)

Comment: first To turn on Windows Firewall and then try

Click the Start button Start button. In the search box, type Windows Firewall, and then, in the list of results, click Windows Firewall.
In the navigation pane, click Turn Windows Firewall on or off.

For each group of settings shown, select Turn on Windows Firewall, and then click OK.

Comment: Or you can google it: `0x80070643 - fatal error during installation`

Comment: again it's showing me same error which i have told you above....

Comment: If you talk about my machine configuration so i have .NET framework 4.0 installed in the machine. OS is Windows 8.1. I don't have any beta versions of neither .net framwork nor MVC installed in the machine.